# SharePoint Online - View Only access is able to view latest draft versions

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, access, content-approval

I have the document library settings enabled for content approval.

Require content approval for submitted items? Yes

Create Major and minor versions.

Who should see draft items in this document library?

Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)

Not only that. I have created a custom permission level not to view versions. This is the access i provided to view only access holders.

However, the users with just this custom view only access is able to view latest draft document. The content approval is still in draft.

Please help us fix this. This is very urgent.[image]

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of the versioning settings and the custom permission. It will help us analyze the situation.